# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addControl')

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to writing unit tests in Angular. In ngOnInit() function of my angular component, I am creating a FormGroup and initializing it. But running detectChanges() is giving me
" Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addControl') " this error.
I am attaching a part of my code of ngOnInit and spec.ts file below for reference.

component.ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.fragmentTypeData = this.data?.fragmentType;
this.fragmentSubTypeData = this.data?.fragmentSubType;
this.allFragmentsList = this.data?.allFragmentsList;

this.addMaintenanceReqFG = this.fb.group({
  description: new FormControl(''),
  orgUnitSearch: new FormControl(''),
  portfolioSearch: new FormControl(''),
  id: [],
  type: [],
  ssrid: [[Validators.required]],
  environment: ['', [Validators.required]],
  startDateTime: [moment(new Date()).add(5, 'm'), [Validators.required]],
  endDateTime: [moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'), [Validators.required]],
  notificationSubscriptions: this.fb.array([]),
  isRepeat: [false],
  isSIMSActionRequired: [false],
  isDynatraceActionRequired: [false],
  isMaintenancePageRequired: [false],
  isAPMActionRequired: [false],
  isHPOMiActionRequired: [false],
  ssridSearch: [],
  fragments: this.fb.array([]),
});

this.isEdit = false;
if (this.fragmentTypeData?.toLowerCase() === 'turbonomic') {
  this.addMaintenanceReqFG.addControl('hostName', new FormControl('', [Validators.required]));
} else {
  this.addMaintenanceReqFG.addControl('hostName', new FormControl(''));
}

this.filteredOptions = this.applicationOptions;

let rulesFormArray = this.addMaintenanceReqFG.get('fragments') as FormArray;

let newRuleFG = this.getFragmentsForm();

if (this.data?.fragmentType != undefined && this.data?.fragmentSubType != undefined) {
  newRuleFG.controls.fragmentType.patchValue(this.data?.fragmentType);
  newRuleFG.controls.fragmentSubType.patchValue(this.data?.fragmentSubType);

  this.GetFragmentDuration(newRuleFG, this.data?.fragmentType, this.data?.fragmentSubType);
  rulesFormArray.push(newRuleFG);
}

if (undefined !== this.data?.id) {
  this.isEdit = true;
  this.filteredOptions = [];
  this.orgUnitOptions = [];
  this.portfolioOptions = [];

  this.addMaintenanceReqFG.addControl('comments', new FormControl('', [Validators.required]));
  this.restService.getApplicationBySSRID(this.data.ssrId).subscribe(
    (resp) => {
      this.addMaintenanceReqFG.controls.orgUnitSearch.patchValue(resp.data[0].orgUnit);
      this.addMaintenanceReqFG.controls.portfolioSearch.patchValue(resp.data[0].portfolio);

      this.orgUnitOptions = [];
      this.portfolioOptions = [];
      this.orgUnitOptions = [resp.data[0].orgUnit];
      this.portfolioOptions = [resp.data[0].portfolio];
    }, error => {
   ...
   ...
   more code
   ...
   ...
    });
```

spec.ts:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { compilePipeFromMetadata } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MessageService } from '@slb-dls/angular-material/notification';
import { AppInsightMonitoringService } from '../services/appInsightsMonitoring.service';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { RestService } from '../services/rest.service';

import { AddMaintenanceWindowComponent } from './add-maintenance-window.component';

fdescribe('AddMaintenanceWindowComponent', () => {
let component: AddMaintenanceWindowComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddMaintenanceWindowComponent>;
let mockMatDialog;
let mockMatDialogRef;
let mockFormBuilder;
let mockAuthService;
let mockRestService;
let mockMessageService;
let mockAppInsightMonitoringService;
let mockRenderer2;
let mockDatePipe;
let mock_MAT_DIALOG_DATA;

beforeEach(async(() => {

mock_MAT_DIALOG_DATA = jasmine.createSpyObj(['allApplicationsList']);
mockFormBuilder = jasmine.createSpyObj(['group' , 'array']);

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [ AddMaintenanceWindowComponent ],
  providers : [
    {provide : MatDialog , useValue : mockMatDialog},
    {provide : MatDialogRef , useValue : mockMatDialogRef},
    {provide : FormBuilder , useValue : mockFormBuilder},
    {provide : AuthService , useValue : mockAuthService},
    {provide : RestService , useValue : mockRestService},
    {provide : MessageService , useValue : mockMessageService},
    {provide : AppInsightMonitoringService , useValue : mockAppInsightMonitoringService},
    {provide : Renderer2 , useValue : mockRenderer2},
    {provide : DatePipe , useValue : mockDatePipe},
    {provide : MAT_DIALOG_DATA , useValue : mock_MAT_DIALOG_DATA}
  ]
})
.compileComponents();
}));
```

Removing detectChanges is making the test case run fine.
How do I define the FormGroup in my spec.ts to make the test run?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your component is dependent on FormBuilder, but in your test you are only providing a mock. So the component has no possibility to actually build a form
2. In tests, ngOnInit is called when fixture.detectChanges() is called. Therefore you only get the error when detectChanges is part of your test.

Conclusion: If it is your components task to create and populate a Form, you should provide FormBuilder in your TestBed:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { compilePipeFromMetadata } from '@angular/compiler';
import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MessageService } from '@slb-dls/angular-material/notification';
import { AppInsightMonitoringService } from '../services/appInsightsMonitoring.service';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { RestService } from '../services/rest.service';

import { AddMaintenanceWindowComponent } from './add-maintenance-window.component';

fdescribe('AddMaintenanceWindowComponent', () => {
let component: AddMaintenanceWindowComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddMaintenanceWindowComponent>;
let mockMatDialog;
let mockMatDialogRef;
let mockAuthService;
let mockRestService;
let mockMessageService;
let mockAppInsightMonitoringService;
let mockRenderer2;
let mockDatePipe;
let mock_MAT_DIALOG_DATA;

beforeEach(async(() => {

mock_MAT_DIALOG_DATA = jasmine.createSpyObj(['allApplicationsList']);
mockFormBuilder = jasmine.createSpyObj(['group' , 'array']);

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [ AddMaintenanceWindowComponent ],
  providers : [
    FormBuilder,
    {provide : MatDialog , useValue : mockMatDialog},
    {provide : MatDialogRef , useValue : mockMatDialogRef},
    {provide : AuthService , useValue : mockAuthService},
    {provide : RestService , useValue : mockRestService},
    {provide : MessageService , useValue : mockMessageService},
    {provide : AppInsightMonitoringService , useValue : mockAppInsightMonitoringService},
    {provide : Renderer2 , useValue : mockRenderer2},
    {provide : DatePipe , useValue : mockDatePipe},
    {provide : MAT_DIALOG_DATA , useValue : mock_MAT_DIALOG_DATA}
  ]
})
.compileComponents();
}));
```